# Create buttons from StringArray and set onClickListener

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, dynamic, android-button

I have to get the array and use it to dynamically create onClickListener(). I have used this method to create dynamic buttons. Anyone has any idea how to use an array to dynamically create onClickListener()?

```
for (int i = 0; i < categoryName.size(); i++) {

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(Integer.parseInt(categoryID.get(i).toString()));
    btn.setHint(categoryID.get(i).toString());
    btn.setText(categoryName.get(i)); //another array with the name of the IDS
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //example
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),categoryID.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    buttonLayout.addView(btn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create array of Buttons ? Also do you want to define separate `onClickListener` for each button in the array? Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put only `btn.setOnClicklistener(this);` instead of

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //example
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),categoryID.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

onClick():

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //example
    //you can check its view 
    //here V gives you BtnId 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `categoryName` and `categoryID` arrays be `final`.